# Is $10^{10}$ Planck Times sufficient to create all the mass-energy in the universe

Tags: cosmology, time, big-bang

I understand that there are $10^{T_P}$ (Planck Times that I think of as Planck Seconds) during the interval beginning with the interval $10^{-43}$ seconds and the end of the inflationary epoch at $10^{-32}$ seconds.  During this interval spacetime inflated faster than the speed of light.

By my admittedly limited understanding of quantum mechanics and special relativity the temporarily real components of the virtual particle/antiparticle pairs being created during this period would not be able to reconnect with each other.  Once each half of the pair became "real" the speed of its motion would be constrained by Einstein's speed limit.  Since the universe itself was expanding much faster than that speed limit the distance being created through inflation would always exceed the time available to close that distance.  It seems that this would be true for every particle and antiparticle created during the first $10^{-32}$ seconds of the universe. None of them would be able to interact with any other until the rate of inflation slowed to below the speed of light.

My first question is, do I have this correct?  If not why not?
My second questions is, was there enough time between the Planck epic at $10^{-43}$ seconds and the end of the inflationary epoch at $10^{-32}$ seconds to create enough real particles and antiparticles to account for the current mass and energy of the universe?  For the sake of this question let's assume that a quantum event cannot create a particle/antiparticle pair in less time than $10^{-43}$ seconds.

I am a social security eligible lifelong learner with only a very modest formal introduction to math beyond an introduction to calculus, and physics.  I'd appreciate a response that can be understood by an inquisitive layman.

Comment: Please consider as a possible source of energy the dark energy that is contributing to accelerating the rate of expansion of the universe even today.